# How To Install Windows 7 on Hard disk with VirtualBox?

Tags: installation, wine, virtualbox, windows-7

Now I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and I have VirtualBox, I want to install Windows 7 on my other partition, so I can run it from BIOS either from virtualbox

But could I install it to my hdd without running the cd from BIOS, I mean install it from VirtualBox?

All I know when I install it from VirtualBox I only can run Windows 7 from VirtualBox, I can't run it alone from BIOS .

If there is a way please help me, I'm new at Ubuntu

Cause I need to run Adobe Premiere and FL Studio 10. I know I can install it with Windows, but I'm having problem when I installed FL studio, it's always stuck at the installation, and I know it will be not maximum to run it from VirtualBox

Comment: Shrink the ubuntu partition with Gparted, boot from the windows installation disk, install it to the empty space, and then switch your bootloader back to grub2 if you need to. Are you having trouble booting from the cd?

Comment: im not having a problem, but i think if it could install it from VB it will be easier. and if i install it from bios, can i still run it from VB?

Comment: You can only dual boot and virtualize the same operating system if it is on a second hard drive and you use (link below) to attach the second hdd to the vbox.(ctrl-f Access to entire physical hard disk) And even then, Its kindof risky and what not for a couple different reasons http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html

Comment: Actually you might be able to get away with it just on a separate partition, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: i do seperated my hd, 50 GB to NTFS, and if i install the win 7 on the NTFS HD, can i run it via VirtualBox?

Comment: By HD do you mean Partitions or Hard Drives? I know it will work if you have two hard drives but have not tested if both operating systems are on the same hard drive.

Comment: @apple16 **DO NOT** Install windows when Ubuntu is installed. Dumb windows will just overwrite what's precious to you :D

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but it is complex, and out-topic here.

You can find a [tutorial](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=33356) on the VirtualBox site. To summarize it you need to:

- Configure your virtual machine to be as close as possible to the real hardware, specially the MAC addresses of the virtualiced NICs
- Copy the DMI information from your BIOS to your virtual machine.
- Install Windows 7 in the real hardware
- Create a VDK for the raw disk.
- Create a new user, with raw access to the disk to run the VM
- Make some Vodoo to restore the Windows MBR.
- Install Guest Additions, hope that they don't conflict with real driver.